# How to set viewmodel property from code-behind using Viewmodel-first?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

In my WPF (4.0) application I'm using `Viewmodel-first` pattern. Hence, my viewmodels are created first, then the views - using data templates. A working demo can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Now, from within the created views (code-behind), I need to modify a property of the viewmodel. In a `View-first` approach, I would simply access a named viewmodel instance. However, the `Viewmodel-first` approach does not allow for this. There is a viewmodel, but the view does not care what it is.

### BAD:

Sure you can get hold of the `DataContext` and use it, but that effectively couples the view and t
the viewmodel.

```
private void MyView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;
}
```

There has to be a recommended pattern for this. Commands? Messages? Please help!

**Q: How do I modify (set a property) the active viewmodel?**

Comment: *"I need to modify a property of the viewmodel"* => Most likely this assumption is wrong, and there is an architecturally preferable way of achieving the desired effect. What exactly is that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Bindings to pass data from View to ViewModel and commands to active the ViewModel.

Commands should use a binding to a execute a Command on the ViewModel.

Messages should be used to communicate between ViewModels.

.

Comment: This is tricky. I have some advanced mouse event handlers that rely on data in the viewmodel. If I can't access it, how do I successfully implement mouse/drag logic?

Comment: Have the eventhandlers (in the code behind) raise events that you bind to commands on the viewmodel. Access the data in the viewmodel by exposing the data though properties on the view and bind the viewmodel-properties to these.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So in `XAML` I do something like this? `<local:MyView SomeProperty="{Binding SomeProperty}" />

Comment: Yes. Just remember that in MVVM the View displays the ViewModel. It should be passive, the ViewModel should do the actions/Commands. the only code you should have in the View is the handling of UI events for displaying purposes.

Comment: Should this view property be a `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: The property in the View should be a DependencyProperty, the property of the ViewModel should just call OnPropertyChanged in its setter.

Comment: Actually, I disagree with that the accessing the ViewModel from the View breaks MVVM. The real intention of MVVM is to reuse the ViewModels and Models libraries. The View anyway knows about the ViewModel. If the View behaves itself actively against the VM it breaks nothing.

Comment: In my case there is a VirtualizingWrapPanel without scrolling ability. Somehow, triggered by the user's click (on the button "NextPage") I have to invoke PageDown on the VirtualizingWrapPanel to allow it to render the next portion of data. The VM can't calculate how many items can be rendered at once. So I decided to expose an event to which the View has to be subscribed.

Comment: @engineerspock - you are correct. Thank you, I modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Otherwise View will be aware about View Model.

If this initialization is common across all view models, then you can define the properties/events in `ViewModelBase` and derive all view models from this class.

> Q: How do I modify (set a property) the active viewmodel?

You need to use [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx) pattern for View-ViewModel communication.

You can use your favorite [MVVM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069783/which-mvvm-framework-is-the-best-framework-for-wpf-apps), and nearly all framework support `EventAggregator` (or `MessageBus` or `Enterprise Bus`).

Comment: Is it possible to use this `EventAggregator` pattern to (from within the view) query data from the viewmodel? I have a couple of scenarios where I must make viewmodel queries from code-behind :(